# Foreign keys across different servers

Tags: mysql, database-design, laravel-5

I am looking to have one main database with global data such us users & subscriptions. Additionally, to that, each subscription will have its own database, i refer to this type of databases as children.

Databases will be located on different servers, those servers may change from time to time. Due to this child databases are not able to utilize (as far as I am aware) the benefit of foreign keys on data from the global database. i.e. linking a "tool" in the "tools" table, which has column `user_id = 12`, with the user in the global database.

The question is is it **ok** for me to include columns, in child databases, that will store ids referencing data in the global database? Is there facilities that I can put in place to recreate what foreign keys offer?

I am running MySQL 5.7, InnoDB engine. The system runs on Laravel 5.2.

Comment: 1> You can replicate selected tables. 2> You can have UUID's instead of numbers

Comment: If I replicate global tables then I would have to have extra processed in place to keep data synchronized across multiple databases?

Comment: why do you want to save data in different databases anyway? how would you run a query?

Comment: Once the user is logged in user can select the active subscription. At this stage, we will have two active DB connections, one with the main database and one with the subscription database (child database). The reasons for this separation is because 1. child database can get to around 20-25GB in size. 2. if one database is taken down/compromised/corrupted other databases will not be affected. ..... I don't have a test script yet, which demonstrates a working prototype of me running a query. But, I imagine it would be just like running two databases on a single server but with an extra touch.

Comment: `1. child database can get around 20-25GB` you are savin files in DB? 2> if one server is compromised you've lost 20-25gb worth of data` in addition to your data on the internet for sale and you have no access to it!!

Comment: 1. I am saving data and a lot of it. This data is no use to someone else but the user. 2. I am also thinking on how much time it may take to backup/restore 25GB of data. We have automatic backups in place and in case there is an issue 25GB is quicker to restore then a larger number. I think it takes few minutes to export and back up 5-6GB of data. Not sure about an import, I think it's definitely under 5 minutes.

Comment: How many "child" databases?  1000 would be "a lot".  UUIDs don't scale well; use them only if you need distributed id-generation.  What kind of stuff is in each database?  (Sorry, but it would help us help you.)  Use Slave(s) for backup.

Comment: As for `FOREIGN KEYs` -- They are not a panacea.  When they can't be made to easily work (as in your case), move the equivalent code into your application.

Comment: We are looking possibly at 50-100 "child" databases that would contain 20-25GB and around 1-2k (maybe even more) "child" databases that would contain less than 1GB in data. In regards to data, we are talking statistical data, a lot of parameters with varied values. Statistical data is stored in 7-8 tables; in one table we define records and in another, we define parameters using "meta" type of table. Other tables have a common type of data and will be very small in size.

Comment: In regards to params in the parameters table; each record may have anywhere from 8 to 512 parameters for each record.